# Link OVH mysql database to a minecraft server

Tags: mysql, database, server, minecraft, ovh

I have a mysql database hosted on OVH and a Minecraft server hosted on PrivateHeberg. I need to synchronize my Minecraft server with the database to know stats about players on my website.

The server plugin I am using ask for these informations about my database but I can't figure out where to find the host and the port of the database on OVH.

```
    host:
    port: 
    databaseName: ''
    dataTableName: 'eco_accounts'
    user: ''
    password: ''
    #SSL connection.
    sslEnabled: false
```

Here are the only informations I have in OVH :

[image: Info ovh]

Comment: What kind of OVH database are you using ? CloudDB ? PrivateSQL ? SharedSQL ?

Answer (score 0):

```
I tried translating the 2 things for you (left side plugin/skript/...) Right side (OVH)
host: = Server address
port: = 3306 #(Default port)
databaseName: '' = #Database name
dataTableName: 'eco_accounts'
user: '' = #Username
password: '' #= (The password you have made for the database)
SSL connection.
sslEnabled: false
```

I hope this helped

Answer (score -1):

The problem came from OVH.

OVH block all the remote connections to their database and you cannot active them even for one host only.

if you have an OVH database be careful with this.